# How to avoid unnessessary type check and what pattern or behavior is correct for types from API responce?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I am using a typescript for the back-end app and don't understand quite a simple thing I guess. But searching for articles on Google doesn't bring me confidence at all.

Imagine I am receiving an answer from the API endpoint, the usual schema is something like this:

```js
some_array: [
  { key: value },
  { key: value },
  { key: string || number || nested object }
]
number_key: 12,
string_key: 'string'
```

As you might see, it's not 100% static, sometimes in the `some_array` field (which is actually 100% array on success) could be almost any data in object value.

..and with some chance, I could receive an error or something like that.

Well, typescript brings as safety with types, but I don't understand, how it could be safe when I could receive almost `any` response from endpoint?

For example, what's the difference between:

**api as any**

```js
//inside async function
const api: any = await fetch('/endpoint');

//I should check responce types manually and to avoid incorrect types
if (!api|| !Array.isArray(api.some_array) || !api.some_array.length) return

for (const document of api.some_array) {
  //any function or action
}
```

and **api as predefined interface**

```js
interface ApiResp = {
  some_array: { [key: string]: any }[]
  number_key: number
  string_key: string
}

//inside async function
const api: ApiResp = await fetch('/endpoint');

// if (api) ... but should I check only for api, since the interface of api is predefined?


for (const document of api.some_array) {
  //any function or action
}
```

Does in second option, I could no longer check types like `if (!api|| !Array.isArray(api.some_array) || !api.some_array.length) return` and all incorrect type responces will `throw error` on receiving (in `const api`) after compile to `js` code? So I could just check the existance of `api` only, like `if (api) ....` ?

Or, for example, if the actual response from API doesn't suit the `interface` it will still try to reach to `for of` loop and throw an error there? (because there is no such field as `some_array` in endpoint responses with errors like: `{error: 404}`?

Comment: I use `io-ts` to type data on the application edge (any io basically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is not intended for run-time type checking. It's a purely compile-time type system that is meant to reduce coding errors that easily occur when writing in a non statically-type language. So when you say, "I don't see how it can be safe when I can receive almost any response from endpoint" you are mistaking runtime safety and compile time safety.

If you want runtime safety, and the objects you are receiving from the endpoint are highly varying, then you will need to handle those varying types either "manually", with type checks like `!Array.isArray(api.some_array)`, or using some library like `io-ts` as suggested by zerkms in the comments.

Having determined the type you have received, you may then be able to cast your objects to some static typescript interface so that you can work with them "safely", that is without making type mistakes that won't be picked up until you run the code.

In reality, a good API should guarantee some type of consistent response that you can express in typescript types. If it doesn't, then that is not the type of problem that typescript can solve.